# While loop makes one more loop after it hits break

Tags: c++

I got small tic tac toe made with methods. However it doesn't work as expected. After having 3 in row it doesn't exits the loop immediately but makes one more execution and then ends it.

```
while(1){                  // infinite loop until someone has won, or the board is full
   game.printBoard();         //prints the board
   game.move();               // player enters a move
   if(game.checkWin())        //returns 1 if there are 3 in row by same mark or 0 if
   //                          the condition is not met 
   {
        break;
   }

}   // end of while loop
```

After having 3 in row it goes to the function "game.checkWin()" and is supposed to return 1 and execute the break statement and end the while loop.

Some code from checkWin():

```
bool TicTacToe::checkWin()    //this function belongs to a calss
{
     //checks for 3 in row 1-2-3 by the same mark, this is made for all combinations
    if(_board[0] == _turn && _board[1] == _turn && _board[2] == _turn)
    {
        cout << _turn << " has won the match by: 1-2-3\n";
        return 1;       // returns 1 meaning that somebody has won
    }
   ......   //same code as above but with different positions
    return 0    // returns 0 meaning that nobody has met the winning conditions
}     // ends of the function
```

EDIT:
some rest of the code

```
class TicTacToe
{
public:
    void setBoard(); //sets the board
    void printBoard(); //prints the board
    void move();   // user makes a move
    bool checkInput(); // checking whether the move is valid
    bool checkWin(); //chekcs for win

private:
    char _turn = 'X'; // players turn
    char _board[9]; // the board
    int _position; // the int used for cin
};

void TicTacToe::move()   // user is about to enter a move
{
    if(checkInput())    // let user enter a valid move
    {
        _board[_position - 1] = _turn;  // setting the board to it's mark
        (_turn == 'X')? _turn = 'O': _turn = 'X'; // switching from X to O and vice versa
    }
}

bool TicTacToe::checkInput()   // function called only with the TicTacToe::move() function
{
    cout << "It is " << _turn << " turn!\n";
    cout << "Please enter one of the available squares!\n";
    cin >> _position;
    if (!(_position >= 1 && _position <= 9))
    {
        cout << "Error! Invalid input!\n";
        return 0;   //meaning the user is not allowed to enter that position
    }
    else if(_board[_position - 1] != '_')
    {
        cout << "Error! There is already a mark!\nPlease enter another square!\n";
        return 0;  //meaning the user is not allowed to enter that position
    }
    return 1; //means that position is valid and proceeds to change the board
} // end of the function

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to TicTacToe!\n";
    TicTacToe game;
    game.setBoard();
    while(1){
    .......          // some code already shown above
    }              // end of while loop
    cout << "Thank you for playing!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A guess is that some of the other "different positions" doesn't do the check correctly or forgets to return 1.

Comment: Add more (`cout`) statements to help you debug. Especially near the `return` statements of each function to show what's actually getting returned.  Or use your IDE's debugger to step through the code.

Comment: They are exactly the same, but with different position on _board. However it also doesn't exits the loop immediately even if it has 3 marks on the positions given in the code above.

Comment: You have not given us enough code to reproduce the problem. Can you prepare a [minimal complete solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @selbie I got cout before the return, I've already made and cout for every call on the check function, and it prints out as expected except it prints one more time after having 3 in row and  the other player enters  a move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in move, you make a move, *change the player*, then check to see if the (now other) player has one.

Comment: thats a logical explanation. Sorry for my newbies code